# Kentico Image Resizing per device profile configuration

Tags: kentico

I suspect that this is more a configuration problem than anything else:

The site has been configured using the default device profiles (phone, tablet, desktop) and in settings -> content ->content management -> resize images according to device profile is enabled.

However the images aren't resizing. The sample page I am using contains 2 images served up via the media library so resolve to /getmedia/etc. and I'm using physical devices to double check with. From what I understand the settings listed above should have been all I needed to set?

Comment: What version are you using?  Is your site currently responsive?

Comment: @BrendenKehren Version 11 and yes

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest not using device profiles if you're using a responsive design.  Using device profiles and responsive is not really recommended.  I'd highly recommend checking out [responsive images](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/developing-websites/managing-responsive-images) instead of device profiles.